# Install manpage of jdk?

Tags: software-installation, man

I followed [this link](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/1471) to install jdk1.7.0. But when I `man javac`, there is no manpage for that. (Note: Before the installation, `man javac` gives the manpage for gij.)

```
$ man javac
man: can't resolve /usr/share/man/man1/javac.1.gz: No such file or directory
No manual entry for javac
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

I wonder how can I make `man javac` and other java related commands work?

Here is the `man1` dir under the installed dir:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_67/man/man1/
appletviewer.1  jarsigner.1       javah.1     jdb.1    jps.1         jstatd.1        pack200.1      schemagen.1   wsgen.1
apt.1           java.1            javap.1     jhat.1   jrunscript.1  jvisualvm.1     policytool.1   serialver.1   wsimport.1
extcheck.1      javac.1           javaws.1    jinfo.1  jsadebugd.1   keytool.1       rmic.1         servertool.1  xjc.1
idlj.1          javadoc.1         jcmd.1      jmap.1   jstack.1      native2ascii.1  rmid.1         tnameserv.1
jar.1           javafxpackager.1  jconsole.1  jmc.1    jstat.1       orbd.1          rmiregistry.1  unpack200.1
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/60765/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-manpath-or-infopath

Answer (score 1):

Most of packages that doesn't comes with their man pages in the binary packages (in Debian based distros), instead use a package with the `-doc` suffix. In the case of OpenJDK, depending the version it could be `openjdk-8-doc` or `openjdk-7-doc`. If you install the `default-jdk` or `default-jre` metapackage, you can use the `default-jdk-doc` to use the default documentation also.